# Reducing number of refills in fgets()

Tags: c++, c, parsing, io, fgets

My C++ program reads in a textual file stream that is delimited by newline characters. For performance reasons, I am using C I/O functions to process these data. I am using `fgets()` to read a line of this textual file stream into a `char *` buffer; the buffer gets processed with other functions not relevant to this question. Lines are read in until EOF.

Behind the scenes in `fgets()` — looking at a source code implementation for OpenBSD, for instance — it looks like this function will refill the `FILE` pointer's internal buffer once it runs out of characters to parse for newlines (assuming there are more characters to look through and ignoring other termination conditions, for a moment).

**Problem:** From profiling with `gprof`, it looks like a lot of time is spent on reading in and processing input, not so much elsewhere in the program, which is generally efficient. To improve performance, I'd like to explore reducing the total I/O overhead of this program, where I am working with very large (multi-GB) inputs.

**Question:** Perhaps minimizing refills is one way to keep file I/O to a minimum. Is there a (platform-independent) way to adjust the size of the internal buffer that the `FILE` pointer uses, or would I need to write a custom `fgets()`-like function with my own buffer? Are there other strategies for reducing overall I/O overhead (seeks, reads, etc.) when parsing text files?

---

**Note:** I apologize but I failed to indicate what kind of streams I am working with — I should state more clearly that my application reads from `stdin` (standard input) as well as regular files.

Comment: You say you're using `fgets()` rather than, say, C++'s `std::getline()` for performance reasons. Have you measured the performance and found it to be significant? My guess is that the unavoidable overhead of just reading the data will dominate any savings gained by using a different input function. But that's only a guess.

Comment: If it's appropriate to your situation, you could use OS functions such as `mmap`

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I had an answer (now deleted) that suggested `mmap` but the OP clarified that was not appropriate due to the requirement to read from `stdin`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I haven't seen much improvement from `mmap` over serially reading files. As a comment in Greg Hewgill's now-deleted answer says, `mmap` can help with files accessed in a less linear fashion.

Comment: The main problem with `fgets` is the extra data copy. If you don't require NUL-terminated strings, you can probably speed things up by directly reading an aligned 8k buffer at a time and finding the newlines yourself. It's possible that your unspecified string processing can just use newline instead of NUL as a terminator; otherwise, I'd suggest using `strchr` instead of a manual byte-by-byte search; the glibc implementation will search 8 bytes at a time on 64-bit architecture, which is noticeably faster than a byte-by-byte loop. YMMV. (And beware of premature optimization, as always.)

Answer (score 4):

The [`setbuf(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setbuf.3.html) family of functions allow you to specify the buffering for a `FILE*`.

Specifically, `setbuffer` and `setvbuf` allow you to assign a buffer you allocate to be associated with the file. Or, you can simply specify the size to be `malloc`ed.

See also the GNU libc documentation on [Controlling Buffering](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Controlling-Buffering.html).

Comment: Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment - Stevens & Rago devotes part of the File I/O section to the effect of buffering in this situation.  Basically, increasing the buffer size sped up I/O to a point and then increased buffer size had no further effect.  This is implementation dependent as well.  Point: there is a limit to buffering and performance.